# Addressing the customer by their first name in CRM 2011 email templates triggered by Service Activity workflows

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

If a customer schedules a service activity using my web application and I want to send them an automated confirmation email, it seems I have two options:

- Have the workflow create and send a new email message. On this view (see below), you can use fields from related entities on the service activity (e.g. the customer's first name).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAlFe.png]

- Have the workflow use an email template. It seems that email templates do not allow you to access fields from a related entity, like first name, so the only option here is to address the customer by their FULL name.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkimJ.png]

Are there any solutions that I missed, or am I stuck with the first option if I want to address the customer in a personal, natural way on this automated email?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, the CRM is pretty limited on that aspect. The best workaround is to add the `firstname` to the `Service Activity` entity. May suit you or not. Otherwise, it is achievable through a the SDK, but that's much more complicated if you don't already use it.